# What Can I do to improve the 96% (f-score) in my CNN Keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I'm running a project with roughly 22000 images (11000 each class) with ResNet50 fine tuning. This is my code:

```py
base_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=True, input_shape=(224,224,3))

head_model = base_model.get_layer("conv5_block1_1_conv").output
    
head_model = Dropout(0.75)(head_model)
head_model = Flatten()(head_model)
head_model = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(head_model)
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=head_model)
model.summary()
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
    
adam = Adam(lr=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer= adam, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(TRAIN_DIR,
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=50,
    class_mode='binary')
model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=100)

model.save("asd.h5")
```

With this model I reached 96 % of f-score. What method I can apply to improve its accuracy? I already tried include colormap as preprocessing and Include Dense layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're a lot of techniques:

1. You can change the structure of model. Add or remove some layers (and not only `Dense` layers). Or use other pretrained model.
2. Change the optimizer. For example, despite the `Adam` another popular optimizer is `RMSprop`. You can also try to tune optimizer's hyperparameters.
3. Preprocess data. You can do zoom, shear and etc.